# Comparing regression coefficients in the same multiple regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, differences

In a multiple regression, I want to test if  IV1's prediction of the DV is significantly different than that of IV2's. IV1 & IV2 are dependent (say, height and weight measured in all subjects in a single sample, to see if they predict happiness). 
Specifically, if I hypothesized that the higher (IV1) a person is, and the lighter he is (IV2), the happier he is (DV). 
height and weight have both been standardized, and so was the measure of happiness (Let's ignore multicolinearity problem for now). 
Results showed:

```
height:  B=0.23,  SE=0.15, t=1.5, p=0.14 CI[-0.08:0.53]

weight: B=-0.29, SE=0.15, t=-2.0,p=0.05 CI[-0.003:-0.58]
```

Comment: You just want to test if .23 is different from-.29?

Comment: Sorry for the late response.... and yes :-)